# Why is version of transitiv dependency not updated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have the following configuration in my gradle.build. I try to update the version of spring-boot-starter-actuator to 2.7.11 by using constriants but i does not work. Why are constraints not working in this case? The dependency of spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure is not defined explicit.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.10'
}

    dependencies {
....
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

        constraints {
        implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:2.7.11') {
            because('vulnerabilities in previous versions.')
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't upgrade parts of Spring Boot to a newer version, never mix jars from different versions of a framework that will lead to all sorts of issues. Upgrade Spring Boot in its totally to 2.7.11

Comment: it's only an example but when a library of spring boot has a critical bug then i have to update the single library. patch update should normaly not be a problem. I just wonder why in this case constraints does not work?

Comment: THe library is Spring Boot not a part of Spring Boot. It will lead to all sorts of weird issues, so upgrade Spring Boot (it applies to other frameworks as well). Not to mention that this will also lead to upgrades when you actually do upgrade Spring Boot to a newer version, then this one will stick around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You faced this problem because constraints in Gradle are used to control the versions of dependencies that are transitive.
In your case, you are trying to control the version of a direct dependency, which is `spring-boot-starter-actuator`. The constraint will not work in this case because it only applies to transitive dependencies.

[Here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html) is a good document about constraints in Gradle.

If you want to change the version of a dependency, you can simply specify the version number: (see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter)

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.7.11
}
```

But two Very very important points:

1. never upgrade Spring Boot to a newer version partial, do it totally for overall of project
2. Spring boot 2.7.11 has 7 very serious and Vulnerabilities that warned in [Repository page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.7.11)

Comment: Those 7 vulnerabilities are actually just 1, due to SnakeYaml, which will only be an issue if you are using YAML and are accepting external yaml as input for controllers or binding.